# Swift - Execute code after sometime on receiving a silent notification

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

In my iOS application, I want to execute a piece of code after 5 seconds of receiving a silent notification from Firebase.

The tentative workflow is something like this:

1. A silent notification from Firebase arrives on the device => OK
2. Application extracts some data and displays a local notification => OK
3. After 5 seconds, I want to list the notifications delivered via `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getDeliveredNotifications` => Not OK

In all the above steps, there's no user intervention and the app is always in background.

The attempted code is as follows:

```
//Receive the silent notification
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID 2: \(messageID)")
    }
    showLocalNotification(userInfo: userInfo, fetchCompletionHandler: completionHandler)

    /* This was one of the attempts
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(2)) {
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }
    */
}

//Show Local notification with the data received in silent notification
func showLocalNotification(userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {   
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = NSLocalizedString("notificationTitle", comment: "")
    content.body = NSLocalizedString("notificationBody", comment: "")
    content.userInfo = userInfo

    // Create the request
    let uuidString = UUID().uuidString
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: uuidString, content: content, trigger: nil)
            
    // Schedule the request with the system.
    let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            
    notificationCenter.add(request) { (error) in
        if error != nil {
          // Handle any errors.
            print(error!)
        } else {
            self.startTimer()
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(2)) {
                completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
            }

            //completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)

            /* This was another approach instead of using timer
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(5)) {
                self.deliveredNotifications()
            }
            */
        }
    }
}

// Start timer to wait for 5 seconds
func startTimer() {
    print("starting timer")
    if timer == nil {
        timer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(queue: DispatchQueue.global())
        timer!.schedule(deadline: .now() + .seconds(5))
        timer!.setEventHandler {
            print("in event handler")
            self.deliveredNotifications()
            self.timer = nil
        }
        timer!.resume()
    }
    print("timer started")
}

//List notifications 
func deliveredNotifications() {
    let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    notificationCenter.getDeliveredNotifications(completionHandler:  { notifications -> () in
        print("in dispatch")
        print(notifications.count)
        for request in notifications {
            print(request.request.identifier)
        }           
    })
}
```

In the above code, `print("in event handler")` never gets printed on the console and hence `deliveredNotifications()` does not execute. The other two print messages in `startTimer()` are printed successfully.

However, if I directly call `deliveredNotifications()` after displaying the local notification, it executes fine.

Also, if I launch the app or send another silent notification, the timer callback gets executed but that is not the desired behavior.

So, is there anything that I am missing or I can do to get this working?

I saw some similar questions, but could not achieve anything concrete:

- [Silent push only work properly when second push arrive (app in background)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41327895/silent-push-only-work-properly-when-second-push-arrive-app-in-background)
- [How to clear a remote pushed notification for iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46689396/how-to-clear-a-remote-pushed-notification-for-ios)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your App support background task, can you try something like this:

```
func startTimer() {
    print("starting timer")
    if timer == nil {
        let task = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler: nil)
        timer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(queue: DispatchQueue.global())
        timer!.schedule(deadline: .now() + .seconds(5))
        timer!.setEventHandler {
            print("in event handler")
            self.deliveredNotifications()
            self.timer = nil
            UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(task)
        }
        timer!.resume()
    }
    print("timer started")
}
```

I think the main reason is that you are not starting background task, so as soon as your App enters background, execution stops.

NOTE: You probably need to a `expirationHandler` in case you exceed the allow background time, and do some error handling.